# Can Live Cards be used in an Immersion?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am writing a Google Glass app and up until now, I've used a combination of Static Cards and menus for my UI.  Now I need to display where several timers are in their progression on one card, so it seems like a live card is the way to go.  Because of the nature of the project, this all needs to be in an `Immersion` and so my question is, can I add `LiveCard` instances in with the Static Cards within the Immersion?